# Connecting to Apache Server

Tags: apache, ssh, wamp, lamp, sshd

After I have created my apache server, and installed LAMP, I have portforwarded port 80, and am able to reach the server on any browser using my external IP. When I go to connect to the server through ssh using my terminal on my MacBook, I can only connect to it using the servers inet (IPv4) IP address, and not the external IP address using port 80, for example, I can connect to it using: ssh root@192.168.1.204, but I cannot connect to it using: ssh -p 80 root@'external ip address'
the error I get is: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

PLEASE IF ANYONE CAN HELP! I have been struggling with this for days.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH is port 22, you can't use it to connect to port 80. If you added the port 80 portion to your first command as well, you should see the same error.

Comment: You are actually a legend... Thank you so much, but then what is the point of giving the option to specify the port?

Comment: You would do this if you were port forwarding. Say you needed an SSH sever to listen on another port, as you couldn't get a network admin to allow port 22. You'd in this instance also need to have your SSH server listening on that port. You can telnet to a web server on port 80, but if you don't type HTTP 1.1 headers (i.e. requests) you won't get much.

Comment: You're welcome, could you mark this answered please?